# Getting less number of features in weight vectors as were provided for SVM

Tags: r, svm, feature-selection, ranking

I have trained a SVM with 18881 features and wanted to know the ranking of features. I tried the method given at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390173/svm-equations-from-e1071-r-package for it and found the weight vector by

```
w = t(model$coefs) %*% model$SV
```

On checking `w` by `str(w)`, I get the following:

```
> str(w)
Formal class 'matrix.csr' [package "SparseM"] with 4 slots
  ..@ ra       : num [1:16725] 1198.1 229 107.5 -22.4 408.3 ...
  ..@ ja       : int [1:16725] 381 396 434 447 3262 4802 9187 10398 11856 13896 ...
  ..@ ia       : int [1:2] 1 16726
  ..@ dimension: int [1:2] 1 18881
```

Please explain me the meaning of these @ra etc. I guessed that @ja is giving the column id of feature and @ra is giving the corresponding weight. In that case why number of features is not equal to 18881.

Am I correct when I say that @ja is column id of features?

As was explained in the mentioned stackoverflow answer, I used linear kernal. Can I apply the same method for Radial Kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got the explanation because of help provided in comments at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725917/why-less-number-of-features-being-ranked-in-svm-as-compared-to-actual-provided?noredirect=1#comment43863950_27725917). The sparseM doesn't store the 0 value cells and hence the features having 0 weights are not stored here.

```
ra: Object of class numeric, a real array of nnz elements containing the **non-zero elements** of A.
ja: Object of class integer, an integer array of nnz elements **containing the column indices of the elements stored in ‘ra’**.
ia: Object of class integer, an integer array of nnz elements containing the row indices of the elements stored in ‘ra’.
dimension: Object of class integer, dimension of the matrix
```